# Fullcalendar defaultview 'year' not work google chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, calendar, fullcalendar

This year fullcalendar example only works in mozila firefox, in chrome it breaks in the year 2021. can anyone help me understand why this?

http://embed.plnkr.co/xhahIV/

Comment: breaks how exactly? What goes wrong? I just ran your plunker in the latest Chrome and it did not crash or throw any console errors when moving to the year 2021 (and beyond). You'll need to be more specific about what the problem is.

Comment: P.S. The "year" view is not default functionality in fullCalendar. I assume someone has made a customised version. Therefore, if there is a bug in it, it's not the fault of the fullCalendar maintainer, and you may find that people following the fullCalendar tag don't know the specifics of this type of view. If you really have found a bug you might be better to speak to the person who created this custom version.